# When i add addAndroidDownloads: in react-native-blob-util in react native then Req.body does not go in Api on the Server Side

Tags: react-native

When i add addAndroidDownloads: in react-native-blob-util in react native then Req.body does not go in Api on the Server Side

```
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from 'react-native-blob-util';




const demeData = [{ "height": 448, "mime": "image/jpeg", "modificationDate": "1685633298000", "path": "file:///data/user/0/com.photo_to_pdf/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG-20230601-WA0000.jpg", "size": 57525, "width": 794 }];

    ReactNativeBlobUtil
      .config({
        fileCache: true,
        addAndroidDownloads: {
          useDownloadManager: true,
          notification: true,
          path: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/${title}.pdf`,
          description: 'Working',
        },
      })
      .fetch('POST', `http://${ip}:3000/api/DocxToPDFConvert` ,{
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      demeData
        )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('The file saved to ');
      }).catch((err) => {
       console.log("Not Done");
       });
```

I was expecting req.body but it was undefined